# Best way to edit dead links

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I'm not able to comment on posts so I tried removing the link and explaining it was dead so future people don't have to click through to a useless page. I'm not sure why this was rejected. It said I attempted to comment on a post.

[My suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2062538)

What is the best way to handle this so I know for the future? When you explain your edits does that show up as a comment? ( Should I leave the comment blank for the future edits? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your edit doesn't really improve the post very much. You go from having a post with a broken link, to a post with a message that it used to have a broken link. Neither of these are useful. Instead, I would suggest you remove the entire last line of the post. External links should not be essential to the post. You should usually feel comfortable removing them if they're dead and it isn't possible to find an alternative.

The rejection message about "attempting to reply to the post" was because pointing out a broken link would be appropriate for a comment, but not an edit. Once you have enough reputation, you may comment about a dead link to encourage the post's owner to fix it or remove it themselves. I would do this if I can't find an alternative myself, but the original poster still participates and may be able to.

Edit summaries doesn't show up as comments to users reading the post, but they are displayed to the users who review your edit. Your edit summary was fine, please continue to include one.

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation. That is good stuff to know for the future.

Comment: Thanks for asking. :)

Comment: This is a frustration that I've had for a while on StackOverflow . . . I don't feel that I've got enough to warrant an answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment to even say "Hey, these links are broken."  What's a guy without much rep supposed to do?